# Cakephp 2.4 limit not working while using lower limit and uper limit

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

Below cakephp query returns an empty array result but if I use only `$max_results` it works.
I want to search for a record from two limits (0,10).

This doesn't work.

```
$from = 0;
$max_results = 10;
$this->Model->find('all',array(
      'conditions'=>$condition,
      "order"=>'Model.id DESC',
      'limit'=>"$from,$max_results"
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use offset options-

```
   $from = 0;
    $max_results = 10;
    $this->Model->find('all',array(
          'conditions'=>$condition,
          "order"=>'Model.id DESC',
          'limit'=>"$max_results",
          'offset' => "$from"
    ));
```